# Changing Math Fonts with luaotfload in Plain TeX

Tags: luatex, plain-tex, unicode-math, luaotfload

### Changing Math Fonts with `luaotfload` in Plain LuaTeX

Without a major exposition on all the options tried, here 
is the short of it:

Using Tex Live 2013, LuaTeX, `plain.fmt` and `luaotfload.sty`,
(`luaotfload-tool version 2.2, database version 2.204`), on
both Mac OS X and Windows7, the following TeX does not set
the new math fonts properly.

```
% this works with ConTeXt's LuaTeX-Plain perfectly, except
% that *all* text is rendered in italic, (but that is a 
% problem for another time -- still better than this).
%
\input luaotfload.sty
\font\lmromr   =
    {latinmodernmathregular:mode=base;script=math} at 14pt
\font\lmromi   = 
    {latinmodernmathregular:mode=base;script=math}  at 14pt
\font\lmromsr  = 
    {LatinModernMath-Regular:mode=base;script=math;ssty=0} at 12pt
\font\lmromsi  = 
    {LatinModernMath-Regular:mode=base;script=math;ssty=0} at 12pt
\font\lmromssr = 
    {LatinModernMath-Regular:mode=base;script=math;ssty=1} at 10pt
\font\lmromssi = 
    {LatinModernMath-Regular:mode=base;script=math;ssty=1} at 10pt

\textfont0 = \lmromr  
\scriptfont0 = \lmromsr
\scriptscriptfont0 = \lmromssr
\textfont1 = \lmromi
\scriptfont1 = \lmromsi
\scriptscriptfont1 = \lmromssi
\textfont2 = \lmromr
\scriptfont2 = \lmromsr
\scriptscriptfont2 = \lmromssr
\textfont3 = \lmromr
\scriptfont3 = \lmromsr
\scriptscriptfont3 = \lmromssr

\TeX's “hello world” display math:
$$
x = {{b\pm\sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}\over{2ac}}
$$
Or some inline: $0 = ax^{2} + bx + c$, or
$\sqrt{a\over b}$ 
({\tt\$\\sqrt\{a\\over b\}\$}),
$\sin({\alpha\over\theta})$
({\tt\$\\sin(\{\\alpha\\over\\theta\}}).

\bye
```

All text is upright, and no symbols are displayed. Clearly
my fault, but have no idea how to fix it or what fonts to
use, or which font features to select other than the above.

Main reference: [Khaled Hosny](http://www.khaledhosny.org/node/131). Picked up
ideas from some other searches, but no solutions. And no,
I'm not interested to hear how easy LaTeX or ConTeXt or
XeTeX is =).

Wish somebody makes a `{plain-luatex}` tag.

Comment: You have also to change almost all of the math codes.

Comment: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/morbusg/9388664) for help. Notice the comment on LuaTeX (+ssty0, 1 and 2 instead of just 0 and 1).

Comment: I don't understand why you need to load OTF math fonts for math. Note that you can combine OTF text fonts with Type1 math fonts: they are loaded by `amstex.tex` (for example) by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the encoding difference between Unicode and TeX, you would need to write (almost) all of the mathematical mode definitions. Just to support your minimal, one would need (at least):

```
\def\mathfont{TeXGyreBonumMath-Regular:script=math} % just to make it more obvious
\font\math="\mathfont;+ssty=0" at 14pt
\font\maths="\mathfont;+ssty=1" at .7\fontdimen6\math
\font\mathss="\mathfont;+ssty=2" at .5\fontdimen6\math
\textfont0=\math \scriptfont0=\maths \scriptscriptfont0=\mathss
\fam0

\Umathchardef\pm="2"0"00B1
\def\sqrt{\Uradical"0"221A }
\Umathcodenum`a="1D44E
\Umathcodenum`b="1D44F
\Umathcodenum`c="1D450
\Umathcodenum`x="1D465
\Umathcode`\/="0"0"2215
\Umathcode`\+="2"0"2B
\Umathcode`\=="3"0"3D
\Umathcharnumdef\alpha="1D6FC
\Umathcharnumdef\theta="1D703

\newtoks\mathtttoks\mathtttoks={%
  \Umathcodenum`a="1D68A
  \Umathcodenum`b="1D68B }
\def\tt{\the\mathtttoks}

$$
  x = { b\pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} \over 2ac }
$$
Or some inline: $0 = ax^2 + bx + c$, or $\sqrt{a/b}$
$\tt\sqrt{a/b}$

\bye
```

[image]

I have written some of these (not all, and there's some needless stuff there, too) in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/morbusg/9388664).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [minim-math](https://ctan.org/pkg/minim-math) package for setting up OpenType mathematical fonts with plain LuaTeX. With minim-math, you need only provide font family 0; no other configuration is needed.

Here is your example with minim-math:

```
% Required packages
\input luaotfload.sty
\input minim-math

% Font settings (minim-math provides no defaults)
\font\tenmath   = % normal font
    {Latin Modern Math:mode=base;script=math;ssty=0;} at 10pt
\font\tenmaths  = % script font
    {Latin Modern Math:mode=base;script=math;ssty=1;} at 7pt
\font\tenmathss = % scriptscript font
    {Latin Modern Math:mode=base;script=math;ssty=2;} at 5pt
% Note: only family 0 is required with minim-math
\textfont         0 = \tenmath
\scriptfont       0 = \tenmaths
\scriptscriptfont 0 = \tenmathss

% Here continues your example
\TeX's “hello world” display math:
$$
    x = {{b\pm\sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}\over{2ac}}
$$
Or some inline: $0 = ax^{2} + bx + c$, or
$\sqrt{a\over b}$ 

\bye
```